# Cluster/blob detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I come from cell biology world so please excuse my lack of knowledge beforehand.

I primarily use ImageJ for image processing in which we fit a 2D-Gaussian to detect clusters/blobs/puncta. See image below, for example.

[image]

I am trying to implement a similar pipeline in python and came across `opencv`. I'm using simple blob detector and it works well for nicely isolated clusters and not so well where multiple clusters are clustered together. Below, left image is raw image and right is after tresholding.

[image]

My detector is contouring a "multi-cluster" cluster as a single cluster. Is there a way to segment these multi-cluster clusters more intelligently? Ideally, I'd like to use the same 2D-Gaussian, but am open to anything at this point?

Comment: Can you post one of your original/sample images that you are working with along with the result that you expect? How are you binarizing (thresholding) images?

Answer (score 1):

Try contour detection and see if it works.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
out = image.copy()
out = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

for c in contours:
    cv2.polylines(out,[c],True,(255,0,0),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, @Mercury! I've tried contouring with `findContour()`. The issue is with the larger contours. These larger contours are actually supposed to be multiple smaller clusters/contours. I think my thresholding is not the right approach. I wonder if there's some filtering I can do to make larger clusters look more like a cluster of smaller individual clusters?